# is it possible to use Cloudfront with AWS AppConfig?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-app-config

we have a use-case where we have a configuration file present in AppConfig hosted configuration store and we want use cloudfront to serve that, is it possible?

I tried researching about it a little but couldn't find the possible way of integrating Cloudfront with AppConfig.

Answer (score 0):

You can't connect Cloudfront and AppConfig directly. I think it will be possible if we design the structure below.

Appconfig - Lambda - API Gateway - Cloudfront